# pyjamas vs pyqt OR GWT

Tags: gwt, pyqt, pyjamas

I am not a web application pro but need to start working on a project so I need to know if pyjamas ( or shall I say the javascript generated o/p of pyjamas ) is as good as pyqt in terms of 2d graphics and widget features. I have a desktop python application which has some rich 2d graphics (with animations / collision detection etc..) implemented using pyqt.

Now I am specifically looking for equivalent web client with similar graphics and widget features . Does pyjamas support all the pyqt UI features with same look and feel??

I am also exploring GWT for this since I believe GWT has a good set of UIs and also supports decent 3rd party tools like vaadin,smartgwt but my preference is for pyjamas because its python and I am writing a equivalent pyqt based desktop app so am more comfortable with python then java. Also am not sure if GWTs look and feel would match with that of pyqt based UI on windows.

Any insights would be very helpful

Thanks in advance

Regards
Shyam

Comment: I figured out that there is a qt webkit which is also ported to pyqt using which a web interface can be developed with the same look and feel as a pyqt desktop application. Will explore this further. 

If somebody has any pointers to it then plz suggest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably too late, but if anyone else would need an answer,

Pyjamas' widgets are mostly same as GWT's (most are direct translation from GWT, but we have some own widgets too), and do not target Qt, GTK or any other toolkit.

If you are looking into using webkit, you could get best of the two worlds, and use Pyjamas with PyJD. This way your very same application could be compiled into html/css/javascript and run in web browsers and at the same time you could run it in pyqt-webkit, xulrunner or mshtml with original python code.